# Select control for large amount of data

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, web-controls

I have about 6000 names that I need to display in a select control.  I am using knockout to retrieve these records but because of the large amount returned the page is taking about 30 seconds to load.  Without returning these to the control, it takes just a little over 1 second.

Any suggestions?  Perhaps a different type of select option?

Comment: I don't think the issue is the amount of data but rather how long it takes to render the <select> control with that many options. I remember having a similar issue when using a select control and built a custom control using javascript/css that was 1000% faster than the standard html select control.

Comment: 6000 items is too many, on several fronts.  Amount of data transferred, the browser having to render it, but mainly the user experience - are you really expecting someone to choose items from a list of 6000?  Surely there should be some server side filtering before that amount of data gets in front of the user?

Comment: With that amount of data, I would be looking at an autocomplete or filtering solution.  Allow the user to type the first few characters and then get a filtered list, either from an in memory list or from the server.

Comment: Even on my slow PC (Celeron @ 2GHz) KO appends 5000 options in ~4s. http://jsfiddle.net/2c5wr8u6/ Check if your code does not append names to observable array one-by-one but appends them with `pushAll` or by complete content replacing.

Answer (score 3):

With that amount of data, it's terrible user experience to cram it all inside a `<select>`.

You should, instead, use an autocomplete/typeahead plugin.

There are some implementations for Knockout specifically:

Using Bootstrap: http://billpull.com/knockout-bootstrap/?#typeahead

Using jQuery UI: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete

And some vanilla one's you can connect yourself to Knockout:

Select2: https://select2.github.io/

Completely: http://complete-ly.appspot.com/examples/booking.html

Typeahead: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/